# js: why selecting "select tag".target.type return "select-one" as a naming convention?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand why when I select **`<select>`** and targeting any option

it return `select-one` . why `-one`? can it be in some cases counting more or sth else so naming convention have a useful meaning ?

in the code below I'm comparing between `input` and `select` maybe they'r not relevant but looks interesting.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]').on("change",function(event){
  console.log(event.target.type);
});

$('#foo,#foo2').on("change",function(event){
  console.log(event.target.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="select">

<input type="radio" name="select">

<select id="foo">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
</select>
<select id="foo2">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to distinguish from the case of when you add the `multiple` optional attribute to the `select`. It will then return `select-multiple`.

> `multiple`
>
> This Boolean attribute indicates that multiple options can be selected in the list. If it is not specified, then only one option can
>   be selected at a time. When multiple is specified, most browsers will
>   show a scrolling list box instead of a single line dropdown

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]').on("change",function(event){
  console.log(event.target.type);
});

$('#foo,#foo2').on("change",function(event){
  console.log(event.target.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="select">

<input type="radio" name="select">

<select id="foo">
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
</select>
<select id="foo2" multiple>
  <option value="1">Value1</option>
  <option value="2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks...so it's for distinguish between this two cases